# Installing IIS express 7.5 via WPI (Windows Platform Installer) (Error Code: 2329)

Tags: iis-express

I have problem when install IIS Express 7.5 via web platform installer. It gives me error code: 2329.

DEBUG: Error 2329:  Error deleting file: C:\Config.Msi\3df66fee.rbf

I uploaded the error log [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=38F0378B03409974!106&authkey=!ADyrcL3hgjyASow).  How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem solved with downloading and installing IIS Express 7.5 from Microsoft site

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038

I don't know the reason of why installing IIS from WPI fails, but i guess it is related to permissions in Windows.

---

According to the Anand's answer to my another problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016002/net-4-5-fatal-error-during-installation-of-vs-2012-ultimate-on-windows-7-32bit), both of them have been solved by turning the antivirus off.