# .NET 4.5 fatal error during installation of VS 2012 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

When I try to install **VS 2012 Ultimate** on **Windows 7 32bit SP1**, but it gives me the next error:

> "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 - Fatal error during installation"

My installation log: [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=38F0378B03409974!128&authkey=!ABM7gxQbOjNbo_g)

My vslog.cab file: [here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=38F0378B03409974!127&authkey=!ADcyFHmb6NmKNp4)

[image: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 - Fatal error during installation]

I tried to install .NET 4.5 stand-alone, but it didn't work too. [.NET 4.5 log error](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=38F0378B03409974!129&authkey=!AHFIZhIyhBcM3k4)

Comment: Posting the log file would probably be a good idea.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. But disabling antivirus brings no luck. Can I get any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is caused by antivirus scanner on your machine. 
Can you please check antivirus scanner logs and see if there is an exception logged for c:\config.msi? Also let us know which antivirus you have on the machine? We (Microsoft) would like to reach out to them to change their product to work better with installers.

Log file indicates some other application (like Antivirus scanner) is opening the backup file without FILE_SHARE_DELETE after MSI creates/moves it.

MSI (s) (D8:C8) [11:31:49:844]: Product: Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2329. The arguments are: 32, C:\Config.Msi\b8265.rbf,

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2329. The arguments are: 32, C:\Config.Msi\b8265.rbf,

Workaround: disable antivirus and install .Net 4.5 on the machine then enable antivirus again.

Comment: Thanks man, your workaround worked. I had such problem with installing  IIS Express 7.5, exactly the same error code. I use "ESET Smart Security 3.0.695.0"

Comment: @Kevin.A thanks for confirmation and antivirus product details. We will contact them regarding this issue.

Comment: @Anand I am facing the same problem. I disabled the antivirus but no luck.I am using avira.

Comment: @Rashad, are there any entries in eventvwr? Does this happen on specific machine? Can you try installing .net 4.5 as standalone without using visual studio?

Comment: Hi, I tried disabling my Avast Antivirus but no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal, Same suggestion I made to Rashad above. try installing .net 4.5 separately and then try installing VS.

Comment: I cannot install it separately as well, it fails.

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal, Did you disable antivirus while installing .net4.5?

Comment: Yes I did. Then finally I installed windows 8 anf then The setup completed.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd
Type in the command “net stop WuAuServ” (disable windows update)
Go to Run (you can do this by pressing Win + R) and type in “%windir%” (this command let you go to your windows system folder)
Find the folder “SoftwareDistribution” and rename it as “SDold”
Then, go back your previous command prompt and run the command “net start WuAuServ”
Now, try to install .NET Framework again

Answer (score -2):

Just try to update your .NET Framework to an 4.5 version?

Comment: I tried to install .NET Framework separately, but it didn't work too